# Find the highest rank by reputation that a user ever had

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

Stack Overflow shows the current rank by reputation (e.g. [for me](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/122718?sort=reputationchange#122718)). A few years ago, my rank was much better because I contributed more at that time. How can I find the best rank that I ever had? An approximate solution would be OK, too. I'm just curious to know, but I imagine that this would be useful for writing a job application as well. The reputation rank certainly is a catchy piece of information to demonstrate serious Stack Overflow contribution.

Comment: I guess you're not aware of the 7 word Answer that didn't answer the question that got a user 10K reputation points?

Comment: *"I imagine that this would be useful for writing a job application as well."* I seriously doubt this especially as it's historic. It's like writing "I **used to be** good".